# to_gmaps4rails block not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps, gmaps4rails

don't understand:

in my controller:

```
@json = User.all.to_gmaps4rails do |user|
     "\"Title\": \"#{user.email}\""
end
```

in my view:
     <%=@json%>

result:

```
 [{"longitude": "2.13012", "latitude": "48.8014"}, {"longitude": "-90.556", "latitude": "41.0634"}, {"longitude": "2.35222", "latitude": "48.8566"}, {"longitude": "2.35222", "latitude": "48.8566"}, {"longitude": "2.27174", "latitude": "48.9065"}, {"longitude": "-5.97058", "latitude": "37.3815"}]
```

Why the title isn't processed???

Comment: What version do you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you're using a version prior to 0.10.0 which didn't have this option.

Simply upgrade the gem.